What is a word for an engraving-like marking that can arise on an object during manufacture?
There is a bow. It is designed with a special feature. And in the process of adding that special feature, it had gained a special pattern on its surface. What is a term that describes this pattern? It is not an engraving. It is not an etching. The pattern was not carved after the production but produced as a consequence of the process of production. Also, the pattern is directly link to the special feature of the bow. Like this one
Edit:
Here's one of the sentences I need to use the word for.
He took the bow and ran his hand along the ----. The added draw power that these ---- provided made the bow leagues superior than common bows.

What is the special feature?

This feels like there might be an answer but the OP needs to be much more precise. I guess they don't want to know the wood is laminated but it's unclear what they want. Making a bow involves many processes, but which leaves the marks you want to know, and what marks and how precise and specific are you being?

In general, aspect (esp. a visual one: layered, linear, etc.) vs. a physical property (such as strength, flexibility, etc.). I don't really know what you want. BTW, a fill-in-the-blank sentence is mandatory for SWRs. Welcome and best of luck.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Looking at the photo, the appearance of the bow is due to the wood being laminated - Wikipedia has an article specifically on Laminated bow - and it can be described as having a "laminated finish".

Design is not due to lamination.  Four layers of wood were used for making the bow.

@EMS the laminations are probably exactly what provides the superior draw strength in your example sentence.

I offer

striation
a long, thin line, mark, or strip of colour

from Cambridge Dictionary
The example sentence could be

He took the bow and ran his hand along the striations. The added draw power that the laminations provided made the bow leagues superior to common bows.


Several words come to mind: indentation, depression, groove, gouge. A more general term would be imperfection.
Here’s your filled-in sample sentence (edited for repetition):

He took the bow and ran his hand along its grooves. The added
draw power that these imperfections provided made it leagues
superior than common bows.

